# What happened to nav-header class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

With Bootstrap 2.3.2 you could use the `nav-header` class as follows to create a grouped list.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="nav-header">Group A</li>
    <li><a href="/items/1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/items/2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/items/3">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-header">Group B</li>
    <li><a href="/items/4">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/items/5">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs)

In Bootstrap 3.0.0 the `nav-header` class seems to have been removed, though I can't find any mention of it being removed in the docs. I also can't find a replacement.

Is this kind of functionality still present?  If so, what's the new way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Regarding LESS files and Github project, `nav-list` and `nav-header` has never existed in Bootstrap 3. I guess it has been forgotten.

You can get a similar behavior using this kind of hack:

```css
ul {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px;
}
.nav > li.nav-header > a {
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    
    <li class="nav-header"><a>Group A</a></li>
    <li><a href="/items/1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/items/2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/items/3">Item 3</a></li>
    
    <li class="nav-header"><a>Group B</a></li>
    <li><a href="/items/4">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/items/5">Item 5</a></li>
    
</ul>
```

Wrap your header in a `<a>`, add the class `.disabled` and create your own `.nav-header` class.

**EDIT**
According to [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9139) and [this changelog](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342), `nav-list` has been replaced by `list-group`, but you don't have any real way to get the same behavior for headers.

Comment: Adding `color: #999;` to the CSS makes it a little closer to the Bootstrap 2 appearance.

Answer (score 17):

Even though your nav list isn't a dropdown using the `dropdown-header` css class will work.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="dropdown-header">Group A</li>
    <li><a href="/items/1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/items/3">Item 3</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown-header">Group B</li>
    <li><a href="/items/4">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/items/5">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `dropdown-header` is similar but does not emulate the font weight (bold), color (#999), or transformation (uppercase) of the Bootstrap 2 `navbar-header`. Also it indents the heading relative to the other stacked nav items.